# jQuery 'OR' not working when looping through required input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I'm writing a small required HTML5 attribute fallback for various inputs. It's going pretty well so far, but I'm having trouble when checking a radio button is ':checked' and using the 'OR' || operator in the loop:

```
if (self.val() === '' || self.is(':not(:checked)')) {
```

For some reason when I add this it breaks the script slightly and will indicate that the input fields (type=text) are empty when they're not. Is there a better way at all to loop through and indicate the difference between an input type 'text' and 'radio'?

Here's the loop:

```
var reqClass = $('.required')
        reqClass.each(function(){

            var self = $(this)

            // if empty
            if (self.val() === '' || self.is(':not(:checked)')) {

                // if it doesn't have require-checked class
                if (!self.hasClass('require-checked')) {

                    self.addClass('require-checked')
                    self.parent().append('<span class="form-error">This field is required.</span>')

                }

                e.preventDefault()
                //$('.form-submit').attr('disabled', true)

            // if it's been checked, but there is a value now   
            } else if (self.hasClass('require-checked') && !(self.val() === '')) {

                self.siblings('.form-error').hide()

            }

        })
```

Classes are obviously present for 'fallback' browsers and changed on the fly. Here's a JSFiddle, thank you for any help:

http://jsfiddle.net/cyncV/2/

Comment: I've already built a very solid and small validator, just use it, it will save you time.. http://dropthebit.com/150/validation-styling-semantics-of-forms/

Comment: It does'nt say OR, that's just two lines, and not even a complete stickman ?

Comment: You might want to edit your title.  Implying that `OR` belongs to jQuery is one of those things that is liable to evoke snark around here.

Comment: That is a bad way and slow way to check for a checked element!

Comment: What would you recommend @epascarello?

Comment: The simplest is just `!this.checked` or if you *HAVE* to use jQuery `!self.is(':checked')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A text box is indeed `:not(:checked)` (even if it has text in it), so the text boxes are showing as empty when they are not.

Perhaps something like

```
if (self.val() === '' || self.is(':checkbox:not(:checked)') || self.is(':radio:not(:checked)')
```

Comment: Makes sense, but doesn't seem to work for me Jacob. If you can offer any advice I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I updated your JSFiddle to use the syntax above and it appears to work for me.  What issues are you seeing?

Comment: That's because the `:checkbox` is in fact a `:radio` that's probly why it's not working.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem -- you have a radio button that you're using like a checkbox. (Hint: don't.) OK, updated to cover that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var self = this;

var empty = self.type=='checkbox' ? !self.checked : self.value=='';

if (empty) {
    // do stuff
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ctryT/)

Comment: Thanks adeneo, I've tested on the jsfiddle and it's not quite there, do you have any further advice on what's causing the other inputs to show an error msg too?

Comment: Ahh, I see you used 'this' instead of '$(this)' - was conflicting with what I already had. THank you!

Comment: @Halcyon21 - checking element properties is just easier without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution :

```
var checked = (self.is(':checkbox') || self.is(':radio')) ?  self.is(':not(:checked)') : false;
if (self.val() === '' || checked) {}
```

Just add a little condition that if input is checkbox or radio, it look if it's checked, else it return false. Then pass the result into the if condition.